# How to keep text generated with jQuery centered

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

Ok so I'm making a photo frame designer. For those who are interested  [here it is](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame2). I'm using the jQuery .keyup function to generate text. Here is the jQuery.

```
$('#input').keyup(function() {
    $('.text').html($(this).val());
    $('.text').css("text-align", "center");
});
```

And corresponding HTML.

```
<input id="input" type="text" name="Text" value="Your words here">

<text class="text" transform="matrix(2.4428 0 0 1.5 235 550.5599)" font-family="'ComicSansMS'" font-size="41.6368">Your words here</text>
```

But my CSS doesn't keep it centered as soon as new text is typed.

```
.text {
    fill:white;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif, verdana;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think `<text>` is an `HTML` tag. You might want to tag `SVG`.

Comment: @TJ, He is using `SVG`. It is just not stated on the html he provided.

Comment: Yep... that's why i was asking OP to tag the question with `svg`...

Answer (score 0):

Try change transform html attribute to

```
transform="matrix(2.4428 0 0 1.5 600 550.5599)"
```

Do not use **text-align** property, you are working with SVG, so the correct css property is

```
text-anchor: middle
```

Reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor

Comment: The transform change didn't really work. The text-anchor was helpful though. Except I want it to not be center page but be center in my "frame" or a container.